# Use header option on wp-login page with a second logo

Tags: php, headers

Is it possible to use the header image on top of the wp-login.php page, with placement as it would on any other page?

Customization plugins only support 1 image as the logo, but not a header image.

Thanks.

Comment: You can create your own template page for the login and do whatever you wish. Just call `<?php wp_login_form(); ?>` to display the form.

Answer (score 0):

For anything other than simple CSS tweaks your best bet is to use `wp_login_form()` in a custom Page Template and filter `login_url` to return that instead of wp-login.php:

```
add_filter( 'login_url', 'wpse276598_login_page', 10, 3 );

function wpse276598_login_page( $login_url, $redirect, $force_reauth ) {
    return home_url( '/my-login-page/?redirect_to=' . $redirect );
}
```

If you wanted to redirect all successfully logged-in users to the homepage:

```
function wpse276598_login_page( $login_url, $redirect, $force_reauth ) {
    $redirect = get_home_url();
    return home_url( '/my-login-page/?redirect_to=' . $redirect );
}
```

Comment: if my login page is just called /global-login, then it would just be '/global-login' instead of '/my-login-page/?redirect_to='?

Comment: You'd still need the `?redirect_to` argument in order to pass the user to wherever they were originally going before the interstitial login. For example, if you visit `/wp-admin/` while signed out, the login page will redirect you to `/wp-admin/` on success. Your custom login should ideally replicate that functionality.

Comment: If i just want it to go to the static home page, then how do i replicate that? Insert the link to home?

Comment: Replace $redirect with `get_home_url()`.

Comment: So $login_url, get_home_url, etc?

Comment: And that after the . Aswell?

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Perfect. Would it be possible if users anyhow try to go directly via link to wp-login.php or via a redirect to that page, then all attempts like that on wp-login.php gets sent directly to global-login page instead? as it seems now, people using the direct wp-login is just going to the old login.

Comment: Easiest and least intrusive method would probably be rewriting the URL in your .htaccess